# Use Entire Image Overlay as link Sp page builder

Tags: image, hyperlink, joomla, joomla-extensions, web-frontend

I am new to Joomla and Sp Page builder.
I need to make the Image Overlay addon on joomla clickable, I am aware you can use the title as a link, but I want the whole Image to be clickable. Pls help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNwMl.png)

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom addon (based on image overlay) and adjust the output to have the link containing the image
https://www.joomshaper.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-addon-for-sp-page-builder

Or you can add some jQuery to get the link inside each image overlay and add it outside the container then adjust with some css.

Comment: If you are a Joomla user/developer, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and see if you can help to resolve some of our open Joomla questions there too.

Comment: @Juan N thank you for the suggestion. I'm too new to upvote